# 2darray dynamic allocation in void function

Tags: c++

I wanna allocate 2 by 4 2D-array in void function.
I can allocate it in int function. but i cant in void function.
Why can't i allocate 2dArrays in void function?

this is code.

```
#include <iostream>
void _2DArray(int *** arr)
{
    ** arr = new int * [2];
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        arr[x] = new int[4];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            arr[x][y] = 4*x + y;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **arr = NULL;
    _2DArray(&arr);
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            std::cout << arr[x][y] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I dont know why i cant allocate it.
plz help me.

Comment: What is your compiler error?

Comment: Why not just read up on the standard containers and also pass by reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Create2DArray(int width, int height)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data(height, std::vector<int>(width));

    for (int y = 0; y < data.size(); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < data[y].size(); x++)
        {
            data[y][x] = 4*x + y;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure someone could come up with a one-line replacement for those nested loops, using a lambda..:)

Comment: Also, I think you can just use `(height, width)` as the initializer; the compiler will implicitly convert `width` to `std::vector<int>` because the latter's constructor is not explicit.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, but I wanted to keep it simple for him. Also I didn't know the constructor is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

You've got way too many `*`s in that function argument.  Once you get beyond 2 `*`s you should rethink what you're trying to do.  Having said that, here's how to make that function work.

```
void _2DArray(int *** arr)
{
    *arr = new int * [2];
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        (*arr)[x] = new int[4];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            (*arr)[x][y] = 4*x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [standard](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html), global functions that begin with an underscore are reserved. Try to rename

```
_2DArray()
```

to

```
Create2DArray()
```

From the doc:

> ...reserved names include all external identifiers (global functions and variables) that begin with an underscore (‘_’) and all identifiers regardless of use that begin with either two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved names. This is so that the library and header files can define functions, variables, and macros for internal purposes without risk of conflict with names in user programs.

**EDIT**: @[user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109)'s answer solves your problem as-is. A solution with `std::vector` would have been a better idea, as @[Neil Kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2068573/neil-kirk) suggested